# R 3.1 sapply to a list of files

Tags: r

I want to parse the `read.table()` function to a list of *.txt* files. These files are in my current directory.

```
 my.txt.list <-
 list("subject_test.txt", "subject_train.txt", "X_test.txt", "X_train.txt")
```

Before applying `read.table()` to elements of this list, I want to check if the **dt** has not been already computed and is in a cache directory. **dt** from cache directory are already in my `environment()`, in form of *file_name.dt*

```
 R> ls()
 "subject_test.dt"  "subject_train.dt"
```

In this example, I only want to compute "X_test.txt" and "X_train.txt". I wrote a small function to test if **dt** has already been cached and apply `read.table()`in case not.

```
 my.rt <- function(x,...){
 # apply read.table to txt files if data table is not already cached
 # x is a character vector
 y <- strsplit(x,'.txt')
 y <- paste(y,'.dt',sep = '')
 if (y %in% ls() == FALSE){
     rt <- read.table(x, header = F, sep = "", dec = '.') 
}        
}
```

This function works if I take one element this way :

```
 subject_test.dt <- my.rt('subject_test.txt')
```

Now I want to `sapply` to my files list this way:

```
 my.res <- saply(my.txt.list,my.rt)
```

I have `my.res`as a list of **df**, but the issue is the function compute all files and does take into account already computed files.

I must be missing something, but I can't see why.

TY for suggestions.

Comment: The problem is R functions can only return one object. This means you can either submit a vector of file names and have the function loop through them and return a list of data.frames, or, implement the loop outside the function and deal with the data.frames one by one. You need to specify in the question which approach you are trying to implement.

Comment: @ilir : the expected return my.res is a list of df. So it is the first solution. Then I list2env(my.res,environment) to get each df,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the use of `strsplit` in your example. `strsplit` returns a list.

What about this?

```
my.txt.files <- c("subject_test.txt", "subject_train.txt", "X_test.txt", "X_train.txt")
> ls()
[1] "subject_test.dt"  "subject_train.dt"
my.rt <- function(x){
  y <- gsub(".txt", ".dt", x, fixed = T)
  if (!(y %in% ls())) {
    read.table(x, header = F, sep = "", dec = '.') }        
}
my.res <- sapply(my.txt.files, FUN = my.rt)
```

Note that I'm replacing .txt with .dt and I'm doing a "not in". You will get `NULL` entries in the result list if a file is not processed.

This is untested, but I think it should work...

Comment: code run, and I know where do my issue comes from now. First of all, I already tried before with  y <- unlist(strsplit(x,'.txt')), and got same result. In fact, code is working perfetcly. I misunderstood the result. my.res will always be a list of 6 df !! I was waiting for a list of less in case of cached df. But what is good is that it takes account the cached dt as I ran much faster than when processing all files. So job is done.